# Set Validation.ErrorTemplate based on control state

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have modified the default Validation.ErrorTemplate for controls based on TextBoxBase.
So that I have tooltip and a label popping-up, showing the error when the input field get focus.

I would like to remove the default red border when the control has no text but input is required and replace the red border with a star * at the left of the control.

I think that if you have a lot of required fields then the use will be met with a form filled with scary red boxes. The red border should only show up when you have entered a non valid value, like age equals to 223.

So I guess that I want to switch template or part of the template based on a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you can not use [StyleSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Controls.StyleSelector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on TextBox control. It was my wrong. Instead you can use simple converter for switch TextBox styles.

Here is it sample code:

**Model:**

```
public class User : ModelBase
{
    private string _login;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Login can not be empty")]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Login max lenght is 20")]
    public string Login
    {
        get
        {
            return _login;
        }

        set
        {
            _login = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Login");
        }
    }
}
```

Create TextBox styles with custom error template in App.xaml.

**App.xaml**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="AsteriskErrorStyle"
           TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">

        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="AdornedElementPlaceholder" />

                        <TextBlock Foreground="Red"
                                   Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                   FontSize="20"
                                   Text="*"
                                   ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=AdornedElementPlaceholder,  Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="RedBorderErrorStyle"
           TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">

        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border BorderThickness="1.5"
                            BorderBrush="Red">
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="AdornedElementPlaceholder" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

**Converter:**

```
public class TextBoxStyleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string textBoxTex = value.ToString();

        var asteriskErrorStyle = Application.Current.FindResource("AsteriskErrorStyle") as Style;
        var redBorderErrorStyle = Application.Current.FindResource("RedBorderErrorStyle") as Style;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxTex))
        {
            return asteriskErrorStyle;
        }
        else
        {
            return redBorderErrorStyle;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Usages:**

```
<Window.Resources>   
    <styleSelector:TextBoxStyleConverter x:Key="TextBoxStyleConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<TextBox Grid.Column="1"
         Grid.Row="0"
         Margin="5,5,80,5"
         Style="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text,Converter={StaticResource TextBoxStyleConverter}}"
         Text="{Binding Path=User.Login, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" >
```

Sample project you can download [here](https://vk0p2w.dm2302.livefilestore.com/y2pmWWrRgd9zjaIlK-FUjzaA8brjbIW-t6c7DPQhI2kE_1EyPKCEzoVVffVnCI4rheYqsp4hLS6qLnzILgwBf2Sf7hQEpnekMfdzIU_z0dHrzQ/ErrorTemplate.With.StyleSelector.zip?download&psid=1).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [`Binding.ValidatesOnExceptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.validatesonexceptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and  [`Binding.ValidatesOnDataErrors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.validatesondataerrors%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties to `False` to stop the default red `Border` from showing up. And you can apply your asterisk using the `Validation.ErrorTemplate` property, as you seem to have discovered already:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="RedAsteriskValidationTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="*" Foreground="Red" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

You can find more examples, including one using a `Trigger` on the [`Validation.ErrorTemplate` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.errortemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: Of Course I could do that, but I want to drive the UI with my validation rules. And I can have a not empty rule and a range rule for the same property. The not empty should show an asterisk and the range rule should show the border and a small pop-up with the error message.